# How to call recursion with Tower of Hanoi

Tags: java, recursion, towers-of-hanoi

I'm trying to resolve Tower of Hanoi problem; I wrote this code:

```
public class TowersOfHanoi {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      move(5, 1, 3);
      }

   public static void move(int disks, int from, int to) {
      if (disks > 0) {
         int other = 6 - from - to; // sum of index 1+2+3=6
         System.out.println("Move disk from peg " + from + " to " + to);
         move(disks - 1, from, other);
         move(disks - 1, other, to);
         }
   }
}
```

but the result is wrong. The solution in my book is

```
public class TowersOfHanoi {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      move(5, 1, 3);
      }

   public static void move(int disks, int from, int to) {
      if (disks > 0) {
         int other = 6 - from - to; // sum of index 1+2+3=6
         move(disks - 1, from, other);
         System.out.println("Move disk from peg " + from + " to " + to);
         move(disks - 1, other, to);
         }
   }
}
```

why is this? I can't understand the ORDER of these expression:

- first it run `System.out.println()`
- then it run `move(disks - 1, from, other)`
- now it run `System.out.println()` again or run `move(disks - 1, other, to)`?

and WHEN RESTART the block code? Thanx.

Comment: Probably a debugger will help you a lot in learning how recursion works.

Comment: Just print the `disks` value in your println statement to better understand the whole sequence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The tower of hanoi works in a way that -:

1. First you have to move n - 1 disks to the 2nd peg from 1st using 3.
2. Move the last nth disk to 3rd peg.
3. Move the n-1 disks from 2nd peg to peg 3rd peg using 1st.

The book solution is correct in. Your solution is wrong because you have moved the last disk in the beginning, this is against rule of tower of hanoi. I hope you get it.

A bit more elegant and understandable code after some modification where it works for any arbitary n. (Atleast for small values of n due to it exponential complexity)

```
public class TowersOfHanoi {
   public static void main(String[] args) {
      int first = 1, second = 2, third = 3;
      int disk = 5; // or take user input
      move(disk, first, third);
   }

   public static void move(int disks, int first, int second, int third) {
      if (disks > 0) {
              move(disks - 1, first, third, second); // source = first, dest = second
              System.out.println("Move disk from peg " + first+ " to " + third);
              move(disks - 1, second, first, third);  // source = second, dest = third
         }
   }
}
```

Comment: I've tried to understand your algorithm for more than an hour but I've some questions: in the first recursion the `n-1` disk is the smaller one at the top of the first peg? Or I have to consider the first disk on top as `n` and the others as `n-1` until the biggest disk on the bottom?

Comment: I have took the disk numbers in ascending order as their size. So the top-most disk or smallest one is 1 while the bottom (largest) one is n. So in first step we have taken first top n -1 disk (numbered from 1 to n -1). Then place the nth(largest at the bottom)

Comment: Ok so if  I have n=5 disks in the first step I take 4 disks  (disk1 - disk2 - disk3 - disk4) where disk1 is the smallest?

Comment: http://towersofhanoi.info/Animate.aspx. Yes you have to move disk 1, disk 2, disk 3, disk 4 (n - 1) disk in first step. But this step is the recursion calling which will definitely put your all disks (1 - 4) on peg 2. If you are unable to understand it, take a smaller example. for n = 1 it is trivial. for n = 2, you have put the above n-1 disks i.e. disk 1 to 2nd peg, move disk 1 to 3rd peg, then move 2nd disk to 3rd peg.

Comment: for n = 3, calling recursion in first step will move the n - 1 disks, i.e. disk 1 and disk 2 recursively. Then you have to move 3rd disk to 3rd peg (i.e. print the move), then again move n-1 disks from 2nd peg to 3rd (this will be done by recursion). Trust recursion to do work for you. Why? Because of induction.

Comment: And please use debugger and see how the above code is working inside recursion. It will give you more insight of the code working.

Comment: You said "_for n = 2, you have put the above n-1 disks i.e. disk 1 to 2nd peg, move disk 1 to 3rd peg, then move 2nd disk to 3rd peg_" but if I have to create the tower on the 3rd peg I move disk1 from the first peg to the 2nd, then I move disk2 on the 3rd peg and finally I move disk1 from the 2nd peg to the 3rd peg, right?

Comment: Sorry, you are right, its for n = 2, you have put the above n-1 disks i.e. disk 1 to 2nd peg, move disk 1 to 3rd peg, then move 1nd disk to 3rd peg. Its just so much disk around.

Comment: Ok finally I got it! Maybe I'll write my resolution in an answer on this thread just for clarification. Thank you!

Comment: @Bug-Gy Welcome

Answer (score 1):

The idea of the correct solution is that:

1. First you have to move the top n-1 discs from peg "from" to peg "other" recursively.
2. Then you can move the bottom disc from peg "from" to peg "to" - that's the `println` statement.
3. Then you have to move the n-1 discs (which were moved in step 1) from peg "other" to peg "to" recursively.

On the other hand, what you are trying to do in your incorrect solution is move the bottom disc before you moved all the discs stacked above it, which is not a valid move.

Answer (score 0):

So we have `n` disks and 3 pegs, we want to move the disks placed in the 1st peg (the source peg) to the 3rd peg (the target peg); the concept of recursion in this case is:

1. Move all the disks recursively from 1 to `n-1` above the biggest (called `n`) from the 1st peg to the 2nd (the spare peg), **because we want to make space for the biggest disk** and be able to put it in the 3rd peg. This is the *first* sentence `move(disks - 1, from, other);`
2. After have moved all the disk above the biggest we move it to the 3rd peg: as Wikipedia [says](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tower_of_Hanoi#Recursive_solution) this is the simple step and its the *second* sentence
   `System.out.println("Move disk from peg " + from + " to " + to);`
3. In the end move all the `n-1` disks from the 2nd peg to the 3rd recursively **in order to recreate the tower** in the 3rd peg, and its the *last* sentence `move(disks - 1, other, to);`

This algorithm works both with even and odd `n` disks because its a g*eneral solving procedure*, obviously the steps will change depending of the initial number of the disk.

Comment: If you want to know the exact number of steps it will take for n disks and 3 pegs, then it is simply $2^{n} - 1$. This is due to the recursive equation $T(n) = T(n-1) + 1 +T(n - 1)$ or $T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1$, solve it. And you can also modify your method to return int (that will give you number of steps).

Comment: Assumed T(n) as number of access related to the time complexity of the algorithm, the first T(n-1) represent the first step, the +1 represent the print step and the second T(n-1) represent the last step, right?

Comment: Yup. That is correct. Good. I was hoping to not give explanation of what I wrote above and you understood it perfectly.

Comment: Ok, please could you explain me how you get 2^{n} - 1 from T(n) = 2T(n-1) + 1?

Comment: I think https://perkss.github.io/#/MathFundamentals/ConcreteMathematics#text-body this will help you understand the whole solution. A very detailed explanation is given here.